# Prove $\mathcal{F}$ is a field

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$ and $A,B \in \mathcal{F} \implies A \cap B^c \in \mathcal{F}$. How can we prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is a field? Specifically I'm not sure how to prove that $A \in \mathcal{F}\implies A^c \in\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Try $\Omega \cap A^{c}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Omega, A \in \mathcal F \implies \Omega \cap A^c \in \mathcal F$$